# Variations of proof of Liouville theorem for harmonic functions

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, elliptic-equations

Let $u$ be a harmonic on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}|\nabla u|^2 dx \leq C$ for some $C > 0$.  Fix a non-negative smooth function $\phi$ which is identically $1$ on $B_1$ and vanishes identically outside $B_2$.  Pick $M$ so $|\nabla \phi|, |\Delta \phi| \leq M$.   Set $\phi_R(x)=\phi(x/R)$.  We have $|\nabla \phi_R(x)|\leq M/R$ and $|\Delta \phi_R(x)|\leq M/R^2$.

**Question:** I would like to estiamte estimate
$$\int_{\mathbb R} \phi_R |\nabla u|^2$$ in a way such that the right hand side goes to zero as $R \to \infty$.

This question is motivated by a post on [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/380958/prove-liouville-theorem-without-using-mean-value-property?noredirect=1#comment968031_380958) and this argument would be a step in proving the Liouville theorem. I would like the proof to *avoid explicitly using the mean value property*.